# Add an existing marker to embed Google Map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I just started using the Google Maps API and need help understanding how to add an already existing marker to my map.
This is the link to my marker: https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=zmt3eGOnKE00.kcaYcH09dEv8, from which I can get the marker ID. How can I add it to my embedded map? Thanks.

Comment: Clicking on "embed on my site" doesn't work for you? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2L4u5r3/)

Comment: I'm using the API for other functions, like making the map responsive and zooming in or out on resize, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the downloaded KML or a KML network link (from [your map](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=zmt3eGOnKE00.kcaYcH09dEv8)) to display that data in a [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer) on your Google Maps Javascript API v3 map.